# Which books do you suggest before reading David Harari's book "Galois Cohomology and Class Field Theory"

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, galois-theory, book-recommendation

Please give a list of books beginning at undergraduate level which you would recommend which should enable one to understand David Harari's book.

[Link to the book](https://books.google.de/books/about/Galois_Cohomology_and_Class_Field_Theory.html?id=Rf_sDwAAQBAJ&redir_esc=y)

Comment: The ones that fill in the gaps in your background knowledge. This book has an intro telling you the prerequisites and the intended audience (at least if you find a legitimate copy of the book in its entirety). It also has a bibliography. Without knowing your background, it is impossible to tell you what you should read before Harari.

Comment: Note that this is a relatively advanced book, and you are unlikely to be able to understand it after reading only undergraduate level texts. You should probably have read at least one *graduate* level book on abstract algebra, and one on number theory,

Comment: Oh sorry I meant books including the graduate ones, that are necessary.